# Angularjs: change class on audio ended

Tags: angularjs, audio

I have small sample mp3 files that people can listen to, and made a little player with angularjs.
When the play image is clicked, the audio plays and the play images changes to a pause image by changing the class of the image.

I would like the image to change back when the audio has stopped playing

this is the html:

```
<table class="loops">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th ng-if="domein() == 'localhost' || domein() == 'basles.be'" class='tien weg'>Luister</th>
    <th ng-if="domein() == 'basslessons.be'" class='tien weg'>Listen</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th ng-if="domein() == 'localhost' || domein() == 'basles.be'" class='beschrijving'>Beschrijving</th>
    <th ng-if="domein() == 'basslessons.be'" class='beschrijving'>Description</th>
    <th class='tien'>Tempo</th>
    <th class='tien'>Download</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tr ng-animate="'animate'" ng-repeat="item in loops | filter: query | orderBy: sorteren:direction">
  <td>
    <img ng-class="class" ng-alt="play Button" height="25px" width="25px" ng-click="playTrack(item.loop_id)">
  </td>
  <td class="info" ng-if="item.loop_cat == 1">Drum Loop</td>
  <td class="info" ng-if="item.loop_cat == 2">Backing Track</td>
  <td class="info">{{item.beschrijving_nl}}</td>
  <td class="bpm">{{item.loop_bpm}} BPM</td>
  <td><a ng-href="loops/loops.php?serve={{item.loop_link}}"><img src="images/download.png" width="30" height="30" alt="Download WAV" /></a></td>
</tr>
```

Angularjs

```
myApp.controller('myLoopController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
    $http.get('js/loops.json').success(function (data) {
      // some other code
      $scope.class = "playButton play";
      $scope.afspelen = false;
      $scope.audio = new Audio();
      $scope.playTrack = function (file) {
        if(!$scope.afspelen) {
          $scope.audio.src = 'loops/' + file + '-myFile.mp3';
          $scope.audio.play();
          $scope.class = "playButton pause";
          $scope.afspelen = true;
        } else {
          $scope.audio.src = 'loops/' + file + '-myFile.mp3';
          $scope.audio.pause();
          $scope.class = "playButton play";
          $scope.afspelen = false;
        }
      }
      $scope.audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){
        $scope.class = "playButton play";
        $scope.afspelen = false;
        console.log("ended ");
      });
    });
}]);
```

The console outputs "ended", but the class doesn't change back to "playButton play". Any idea why?

(There's probably much to improve in my code, I just started with angularjs, bit at this moment I would just like to get this working)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You probably want to look into the html5 audio element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Comment: I did look into that, but this gives a player that's too big for what I need. I have no place or need for a slider or volume options. I read this article http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-customized-html5-audio-player--webdesign-7081 and searched for many more these last days, but nothing I could use (with just a simple play/stop button)

Comment: Have you tried using ngAudio? http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAudio

Comment: Thx, I'll look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call **$scope.$apply()** if you do anything outside of angular context such as listening for a DOM event (for example your listener $scope.audio.addEventListener('ended'...) ).

So in your code:

```
 $scope.audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){
    $scope.class = "playButton play";
    $scope.afspelen = false;
    $scope.$apply();  // <<<<
    console.log("ended ");
  });
```

See also [$rootScope.Scope#$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)